# Bayes net: algorithm to calculate joint distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-models

I recently started studying bayesian networks and I am now implementing an exact inference algorithm: enumeration. I am aware of the complexity and inefficiency of this method but I want to fully understand it.

As far as I know there are three basic 'steps':

1. Use Bayes Rule on query / evidence variables.
2. Use summation for hidden variables.
3. Calculate joint distribution.

I've tried a recursive approach as suggested in most documentation of the topic, here's the algorithm I'm using (with python):

```
'''
bayesnet is an instance of a class that hold a bayes net
queryVars is a list of tuples (varname, boolean) to describe the state of a variable, eg. ('B', True)
evidenceVars is a list of tuples (varname, boolean)
'''
def enumerate_method(bayesnet, queryVars, evidenceVars = []):
    #Check evidence vars to apply bayes rule
    if len(evidenceVars):
        return enumerate_method(queryVars + evidenceVars) / enumerate_method(evidenceVars)
    #Check if there are hidden variables left given the query variables
    if len(bayesnet.hiddenVariables(queryVars)):
        #For every hidden variable
        for hiddenvar in bayesnet.hiddenVariables(queryVars):
            return enumerate_method(bayesnet, queryVars + [(hiddenvar, True)]) + enumerate_method(bayesnet, queryVars + [(hiddenvar, False)])

    #Calculate joint distribution of queryVars?

    return bayesnet.joint(queryVars)
```

I am still unsure of how to implement the joint distribution calculation. My BayesNet class stores, for each variable, a name, a list of parents and a list of tuples with the probability given its parents. The bayes network is fully described.

I guess I have to use the chain rule, but I have trouble with that as it brings new expressions with evidence variables that I do not have.

Am I moving on the right direction? If so, could you provide a suggestion on how to calculate the joint distribution.

Comment: In its current form, this seems to be a programming question. Please get rid of the Python code and more to more abstract, readable pseudo code, and formulate your specific question in terms of mathematics, not code.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the result of the chain rule - this is your networks topology basically. Now you need to compute the joint. I would start from "root nodes", i.e. nodes with no parents, and proceed forward (I'm sure you can go the other way too, just more pain):

- Each of the "root nodes" has its "own" joint already. I.e. if your network was just one root node, you're done - just output the CDF.
- Now suppose your network is two "root nodes". What's the joint? Suppose you have two boolean variables A,B with values a,~a,b,~b. The joint is:

  (a,b, P = a*b)

  (a,~b, P = a*~b)

  (~a, b, P = ~a*b)

  (~a,~b, P = ~a*~b)
- This looks like a cartesian product. I.e. you have a cartesian product in the variables, and the value is the product of terms. This is the simple version of a "factor product" - where factor is some unnormalized discrete distribution.
- In general the product of two factors will encounter variables that are common to the factors. Do the cartesian product and throw out all tuples that match on the common variables - this is the join in databases. Compute the probability as before.
- Now you have the factor product. Just use on your graph to compute the joint. Be careful with paths that separate and then join back in the graph.